# Executing script on remote computer using SSH

Tags: ssh

I made a visual basic script (vbs). The script sets the volume to 100 and it starts up a music video on youtube. The script works perfectly fine if I execute it *manually* on computer A. Computer A is a computer with Windows 10 that is connected to the speakers and has a big screen in the common room. I want to SSH in to computer A from another device and execute that script so that music starts playing from the speakers and the youtube video pops up on the screen in the common room, again: it works if I do it manually on the computer itself. SSH itself also works but when I do cscript script_name.vbs in the SSH terminal connected to computer A it executes the script and there are no error messages, whatsoever. But it does not actually do anything on computer A, no volume change and no youtube pop up. How can I make it so that when I execute that script through SSH that it **does** change the volume on computer A and pops up that youtube video on the screen in the common room.
For example this is how I pop up a video with the vb script:

```
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "firefox.exe", https://youtube-link, "", "", 1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the script and describe exactly what happens when you run it. Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: Only the GUI user can launch things which show up on the GUI .. so if your user isn't that user it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran accross it when trying to solve the same problem.  I am using this vb script:

```
On Error Resume Next
set wshshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wshshell.run chr(34) & "d:\icedrive\scripts\Python\MyFirstRepository\DadScheduled.py" & chr(34), 0
set wshshell = Nothing
```

I could not get it to run on the Windows machine over SSH (I suspect it has something to do with running a shell within a shell)

I resolved it by creating a scheduled task in Windows that executes the VBS script and assigned it no schedule (triggers).

Then, via SSH, I run the scheduled task with PowerShell:

```
pwsh -command {Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\Gabe\ComputerMaintenance"}
```

I realize this is a band-aid approach, but it works great for my needs.